# Duplicate records fetching in SQL Server while joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am joining three tables to get the data, but after joining the result set shows duplicate records.

Even if we are add the distinct  key word also getting the multiple records.

This result is 2 times A even after using distinct. My expected result will have only one .

We are provide the table name and structure, after join the first 2 table we are getting the no duplicate records, after join the third table getting the duplicate records.

We are getting the output like this attached the image check it ones

[image]

Tables are

1. [dbo].[t_Oed_followupDetails] tefd
2. [dbo].[t_vehiclenotreachedworkshop_remarks] tvnrw
3. [dbo].[t_vehicleEstimationNotRaised_remarks]

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_Oed_followupDetails]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [breakdownID] [bigint] NULL,
    [vehicleNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [offroadDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [workshopreachedtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [estimationRaisedTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [estimationApprovedtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [workstartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [workendTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [PilotReachedToWs] [datetime] NULL,
    [vehiclereachedtoBacktoBase] [datetime] NULL,
    [VehicleOnroad] [datetime] NULL,
    [lastFollowupTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [progress] [int] NULL,
    [pagetoLoad] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [nextFolloupdate] [datetime] NULL
) 
    
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_vehiclenotreachedworkshop_remarks]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [breakdownid] [bigint] NULL,
    [vehicleno] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [callto] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Reason] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [remarks] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [createdby] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [createdtime] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [popupDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ReasonID] [int] NULL
)
               
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_vehicleEstimationNotRaised_remarks]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [breakdownid] [bigint] NULL,
    [vehicleno] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [callto] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Reason] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [remarks] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [createdby] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [createdtime] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [popupDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ReasonID] [int] NULL
)
```

After joining the 3 tables showing the result but getting the duplicate records.

My join query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    (tefd.breakdownID),
    tefd.vehicleNumber,
    tefd.offroadDate,
    tvnrw.Reason AS Reasonwnr,
    tvnrw.popupDate AS startTimewnr,
    tvnrw.createdtime AS endTimewnr,
    CAST(tvnrw.createdtime - tvnrw.popupDate AS time) AS AHTwnr,
    tvenr.Reason AS ReasonEastNotRaised,
    tvenr.popupDate AS startTimeEastNotRaised,
    tvenr.createdtime AS endTimeEastNotRaised,
    CAST(tvenr.createdtime - tvenr.popupDate AS time) AS AHTEastNotRaised
FROM
    [dbo].[t_Oed_followupDetails] tefd
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[t_vehiclenotreachedworkshop_remarks] tvnrw ON tefd.breakdownID = tvnrw.breakdownid
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[t_vehicleEstimationNotRaised_remarks] tvenr ON tvenr.breakdownid = tefd.breakdownID
WHERE 
    tefd.breakdownid = 415450;
```

Comment: The rows are distinct since they have different `Reasonwnr` and `ReasonEastNotRaised` combinations. Maybe you could [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71016774/edit) your question to explain which is the row you want and why the other three should be discarded.

Comment: Those rows aren't duplicates. They have different values for some of the columns. They are for the same ID, sure, but the rows are `DISTINCT`, as none of the values across the whole row are the same as another in the same set.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a code smell. Don't just throw `DISTINCT` at a query to make duplicates go away. Think about your joins, perhaps you need more conditions, perhaps you need row-numbering etc

Answer (score 0):

The rows aren't duplicate. What is happening is when you join first two tables they are related to each other by 1:1 relationship meaning each record in Table A has exactly 1 record in table B. So there is no redundency. But when you join the third one, it has 1:M relation with Table (A Join B).

Now consider a student registering for multiple subjects. Your join of student with subjects will return data where student columns will have redundant values while subect columns will have distinct values. `DISTINCT()` wont work here because overall the row is unique even if a single column has different value.

What You can do is Use Group by. It will group your columns from A,B and Aggregate columns from C like SUM(), Count() etc. But SQL can't magically remove data just to show you single records. You will have to query your way into getting single records on the cost of data loss